# Filter collection based on custom dexterity field

Tags: plone, dexterity

I would like to make a collection which returns my custom dexterity type if it's "featured" field is true. I have added this field to the catalog... is there anything else I need to do to be able to see it in the collection search terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "I have added this field to the *index*" you mean to the `portal_catalog`?

If yes, you must also configure that index as a new collection criteria. If you are using new style collections you need a Generis Setup import step `registry.xml`. See plone.app.querystring package: https://github.com/plone/plone.app.querystring/blob/master/plone/app/querystring/profiles/default/registry.xml

Comment: There's a good guide here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.collection/2.0b1

Comment: I have added registry.xml and have it showing up as an index and criteria, however adding the criteria doesnt have an effect on the demo results. This is my registry.xml http://pastie.org/9727506 and I can confirm that I have some content with this index showing as "True".

Comment: The xml seems OK... only think I see is that you are referencing a `"plone.app.querystring.field.department` while in the question you are asking for a `featured` field.